# Binary symmetric channel

Tags: binary, entropy

[Binary symmetric matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSYNY.jpg)

A sends $i,j$ and B gets $i,j$.

Does it mean that $A$  != $B$? I would know how to solve this if A would be equal to B, but now  I'm not sure how should I start, when A has 2 values, and B has 4.

I need to find entropies for H(A), H(B).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entropy of a random variable $X$ is
\begin{equation}
H(X) = -\sum_{\mathrm{all~instances~} x \mathrm{~of~} X}p(x)\log_2\left(p(x)\right)
\end{equation}
Thus,
\begin{equation}
H(A) = -p(A_{00})\log_2\left(p(A_{00})\right) -p(A_{11})\log_2\left(p(A_{11})\right)
\end{equation}
and for $H(B)$ we have:
\begin{equation}
H(B) = -p(B_{00})\log_2\left(p(B_{00})\right) -p(B_{01})\log_2\left(p(B_{01})\right) -p(B_{10})\log_2\left(p(B_{10})\right) -p(B_{11})\log_2\left(p(B_{11})\right)
\end{equation}
and therefor, you need to find $p(B_{ij})$. Note that you can use the following (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) for law of total probability):
\begin{equation}
p(B_{ij}) = p(B_{ij}~|A_{00})\times p(A_{00}) + p(B_{ij}~|A_{11})\times p(A_{11})
\end{equation}
to find $p(B_{ij})$. Note that $p(B_{ij}~|A_{00})$ and $p(B_{ij}~|A_{11})$ are channel crossover probabilities. For instance, if probability of flipping a bit by the channel is $q$, then 
\begin{equation}
p(B_{01}~|A_{00}) = (1-q)q
\end{equation}
because in a 2-bit sequence, the first bit is not flipped and the second is flipped. Or
\begin{equation}
p(B_{00}~|A_{11}) = q^2
\end{equation}
because both bits are flipped.

Comment: Thanks, i got the part with H(A) and the part about crossover probabilities.
But still need some clarification for this:
\begin{equation}
p(B_{ij}) = p(B_{ij}~|A_{00})\times p(A_{00}) + p(B_{ij}~|A_{11})\times p(A_{11})
\end{equation}

Comment: This is law of total probability. Find it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability

Comment: Got it, thank you again.